# Flashing Flutter App from VSCode (Android)

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, flutter-hotreload

Is there a way to install the resultant APK to a phone without using "Hot Reload"? The problem being that once the App restarts and the phone is no longer connected to the computer, the recent changes to the App are removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a release version of your app using `flutter run --release`

Comment: `flutter install -d device` does a release build and copies it into place.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Are you sure the copy being installed is a release build? The performance of the app  is really bad compared to 'flutter run --release' :/